# Skobbler polyline doesn't draw line

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using skobbler sdk 2.2 and when I draw a polyline I can't see the inner line.

This is the polyline code:

```js
route.setNodes(routeOverlayPoints);
route.setColor(new float[] { 1f, 0f, 0f, 1f });
route.setOutlineColor(new float[] { 0f, 0f, 1f, 1f });
route.setLineSize(5);
route.setOutlineSize(10);
route.setOutlineDottedPixelsSolid(10);
route.setOutlineDottedPixelsSkip(1);
mapView.addPolyline(route)
```

I'm pretty sure that I saw the red line at one point (zooming in/out, rotating), but I wasn't able to reproduce it.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is... I've tried the provided code in the demo project and the expected result looks "as expected". Can you detail on is the problem? - https://www.dropbox.com/s/46qlagkr11zvy9b/SC20141027-150644.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: After a few tests it came out that this is caused by adding the polyline **before** the map surface was created. If you trigger the adding with `onSurfaceCreated ()` the polyline will be drawn as expected.
Something similar happens  when you come back from a pause state, but then the outline overlaps the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is nothing better so far, I am answering my question.
Adding the polyline before the map surface is created causes the issue.
So if you trigger the polyline drawing with `onSurfaceCreated()` everything works as expected.